# Can the goalkeeper release the ball at their own goal, then save it from going in?

Tags: rules, football, goalkeeper

In [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/ZTx9FMvbpxI?t=13) (should start at 13 seconds), the goalkeeper releases the ball, involuntarily aiming it towards his own goal. Would he be allowed to save it using his hands?

I read [in this article on USSoccer.com](https://www.ussoccer.com/stories/2014/03/17/12/02/playing-the-ball-in-the-goalkeepers-possession) that

> "Parrying" occurs when the goalkeeper controls the ball with the hands by pushing it to an area where it can be played later. By parrying the ball, the goalkeeper has done two things simultaneously:  (1) established control and (2) given up possession. The ball is now free for all to play and the goalkeeper may not play it again with the hands.

This seems to me to indicate that the goalie could not handle the ball, is this correct? On top of that would he be sent off for DOGSO ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's correct. Handling the ball a 2nd time with no other player touching it would lead to an indirect free kick.

[Law 12:](http://theifab.com/laws/fouls-and-misconduct-2018/chapters/indirect-free-kick-2018)

> An indirect free kick is awarded if a goalkeeper, inside their penalty
>   area, commits any of the following offences:
>
> (...)
>   touches the ball with the hands after:
>
> - releasing it and before it has touched another player
> - (...)

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that in the case in the OP's video, giving away an indirect free kick is better than giving away a goal.

Comment: Wouldn't the keeper be sent off for denying a goal scoring opportunity ?

Comment: @JamesWell no, not in this case. Technically this isn't a goal scoring opportunity, even if it could lead to one. It's pretty much like handling a back pass.